# How to properly test onScroll event value in React Native?

Tags: react-native, mocking, jestjs

My code has a lot of animations that run off the same animationRange generated from the same `FlatList` `onScroll`. They all work as intended, but I need to add test coverage to where the animations are being invoked. Unfortunately, I am unaware of how to mock the animationRange.

I have tried mocking `animationRange` with something like this:

```
const mockInterpolation = jest.fn();
const mockAnimationRange = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return { interpolate: mockInterpolation }
});
```

but it's just returning an error when testing and I'm confident it's just because I don't know how to properly mock this value.

```
Here is the Flatlist that sets the animationRange
--------------------
    <FlatList
      onScroll={Animated.event([{
        nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: animationRange } },
      }],
      {
        useNativeDriver: true,
      })}
    />
```

This `animationRange` value appears to be what I need to mock. And it needs to be able to handle the following:

```
export const AnimateScore = (animationRange) => {
  return {
    transform: [
      {
        translateX: animationRange.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, (100)],
          outputRange: [0, screenWidth * 0.125)],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        }),
      },
    ],
  };
};
```

All I am looking for is the proper way to mock this value or test `.interpolate` for the `onScroll`'s offset value.

Thank you in advance.